# Unit test or runtime ActionResult string output response via ExecuteResult?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2, actionresult

## The Question...

What is the best way to Unit Test the **string response** and **content type** from several Controller methods?

### Using...

Each method returns an `ActionResult`, some of which are `ViewResult` responses.  I'm using ASP.NET **MVC 2** RTM and **Moq**.

### Specifically...

I wish to obtain the `TextWriter` from `HttpContext.Response` and have it contain the full string response from an `ActionResult`.

### Why?

#### 1. Within Unit Tests

I want to test some specific if content **does** and **does not** exist with the output.

#### 2. Runtime via worker thread

I use a background worker thread to update static content on remote servers, this content is the output from the Controllers and must be generated as such. Making requests to the same server via HTTP is not advisable because there are many 1000's of files which are updated.

I see the same code being used at both *Runtime* and via *Unit Tests*, as it would be very similar?

### Stumbling block 1

How to correctly setup mocking to not require Routes **Or** call `RegisterRoutes` and `RegisterAllAreas` have the call succeed, currently throws an exception deep inside `BuildManagerWrapper::IBuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies`.

## Sample Code

#### My mocking helpers look like this:

```
public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext()
{
    var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
    var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
    var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
    var writer = new StringWriter();

    var form = new NameValueCollection();
    var queryString = new NameValueCollection();
    request.Setup(r => r.Form).Returns(form);
    request.Setup(r => r.QueryString).Returns(queryString);

    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response.Output).Returns(writer);

    return context.Object;
}

public static void SetFakeControllerContext(this Controller controller)
{
    var httpContext = FakeHttpContext();
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(httpContext);
    ControllerContext context = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData), controller);
    controller.ControllerContext = context;
}
```

#### And my current attempt at a TestMethod is as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CodedJavaScriptAction_Should_Return_JavaScript_Response()
{
    // Arrange
    var controller = new CodedController();
    controller.SetFakeControllerContext();

    // Act
    var result = controller.CodedJavaScript(); // Response is made up as a ViewResult containing JavaScript.
    var controllerContext = controller.ControllerContext;
    var routeData = controllerContext.RouteData;
    routeData.DataTokens.Add("area", "Coded");
    routeData.Values.Add("area", "Coded");
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Coded");
    routeData.Values.Add("action", "CodedJavaScript");

    var response = controllerContext.HttpContext.Response;
    response.Buffer = true;
    var vr = result as ViewResult;
    vr.MasterName = "CodedJavaScript";

    result.ExecuteResult(controllerContext);

    // Assert
    var s = response.Output.ToString();
    Assert.AreEqual("text/javascript", response.ContentType);
    Assert.IsTrue(s.Length > 0);
    // @todo: Further tests to be added here.   

}
```

#### My area, views and shared files are:

-`Areas\Coded\Controllers\CodeController.cs`
-`Areas\Coded\Views\Coded\CodedJavaScript.aspx`
-`Areas\Coded\CodedAreaRegistration.cs`
-`Views\Shared\CodedJavaScript.Master`

**EDIT**: edited to now include both Unit Testing and Runtime execution. Thanks to @Darin Dimitrov for mentioning *Integration Testing* but there is now also a runtime element to this question.

**EDIT**: After some testing and review using some of the source code from  [MvcIntegrationTestFramework as referenced by alexn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216349/unit-test-or-runtime-actionresult-string-output-response-via-executeresult/4233968#4233968). Which uses `AppDomain.CreateDomain` and `SimpleWorkerRequest` to create a new request, I have found that it is not possible to create a new request via this method in a process that already has an active request, due to `static` values used. So this rules this method out.

Probably the same issue but I am now wondering if the result from a **Partial View** can be returned as a string more directly?

Comment: The string response is performed by the view engine much later in the execution pipeline than the controller action. What exactly are you trying to test here: your controllers or your views? Because if it is your controllers it makes absolutely no sense to test the generated string. Just test that the action it returns the proper ActionResult type.

Comment: @Darin Dimtrov Thanks for your comment. I am specifically wanting to obtain the textual content of the ActionResult type. Unfortunately it appears I am wanting to test both controllers and views in combination as query string parameters can create a combination of changes in the both the data selected by the controller and the output from the view. Testing these independently in this case would not be a true test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is no longer unit tests but integration testing because you are no longer testing your application components in isolation and there are great tools that allow you to do this like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [Web Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182538.aspx) in the Ultimate versions of Visual Studio.

The advantage of these tests is that they simulate user requests and cover the entire application behavior. So for a given user request you can assert that your application responds properly. The idea is that you write user scenarios, record them and then you could automate the execution of those tests to assert that your application responds as specified.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I have updated the question to include running via a worker thread and not just via Unit Tests. Your answer is greatly appreciated and valid if it was only for Unit Tests - any thoughts on the Runtime aspect?

Comment: @Dean, I am not sure to quite understand this Runtime aspect. So you are saying that your controller actions basically generate javascript and you are trying to test the output of this actions? The exact javascript which is generated given some user input? What is the background worker thread you are talking about? Is this part of the application you are trying to test or is it some other application making calls to the MVC application? And lastly could you provide an example of an action you are trying to test?

Comment: Yes the actions generate JavaScript but also XML, JSON and plain-text and I wish to under testing test the output. But there is a background worker thread to the MVC application which runs when specific DB values are changed, based on a dirty list which the worker referrers to. The worker looks for these dirty items and pushes (via FTP and HTTP POST) the JavaScript, JSON, XML etc to an alternative location.

Comment: the selenium and web tests solutions require a logged in user and an unlocked session, correct? if so, anything else that would work for this?

Answer (score 2):

I use Steven Sandersons [MvcIntegrationTestFramework](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/06/11/integration-testing-your-aspnet-mvc-application/) with great success. It's very easy to use.

With this, you can easily test output response, **viewdata**, cookies, session and a lot more with very little effort.

You would test the rendered HTML with a test looking something like this:

```
[Test]
public void Output_Contains_String()
{
    appHost.SimulateBrowsingSession(session => {
        var result = session.ProcessRequest("/");
        Assert.IsTrue(result.ResponseText.Contains("string to check for"));
    });
}
```

No mocking and routes registering. Very clean.

As this is technically an integration test, it will take some time to set up and run.

Please let me know if you need any more examples or some more information.

Comment: Looking at the source code to the MVCintegrationTestFramework seems an interesting approach. But for the Runtime (not testing) aspects of my project this it seems expensive to setup an AppInstance etc for each request.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by the Runtime aspect. What you really want to do is an integration test (which tests all components together). You should not use this code in production or handle real requests with it. The views that's generated, are they full web pages with a layout etc? If it's simple text that gets displayed, maybe you could set the output data in ViewData.Model and generate a XmlResult or JsonResult or whatever you need to display, and have them read from ViewData.Model?

Comment: unfortunately the output formats are of several types including a full HTML page, JavaScript, JSON, XML etc. I would much prefer to use the MVC View system and not force the output somewhere it shouldn't quite be. Thanks though.